# ¿Como persistir en postgresql con Angular 7?

Tags: angular, postgresql, typescript

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla para persistir un formulario en una base de datos **postgreSQL** mediante **Angular 7** usando un servicio les dejo mi clase **presupuestos.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PresupuestosService {
  //Url de mi tabla
  presURL = 'localhost/presupuesto.json';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  postPresupuesto(presupuesto: any) {
    const newpres = JSON.stringify(presupuesto);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http.post(this.presURL,newpres,{headers});
  }
}
```

Este servicio lo consumo en mi componente de la siguiente forma:

```
export class PresupuestoComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private presupuestoService: PresupuestosService) {
  }
//Evento del boton Añadir presupuesto
onSubmit() {
    this.presupuesto = this.savePresupuesto();
    this.presupuestoService.postPresupuesto( this.presupuesto );
  }
savePresupuesto() {
    return {
      //Los valores de los campos del formulario
      proveedor: this.presupuestoForm.get('proveedor').value,
      fecha: this.presupuestoForm.get('fecha').value,
      concepto: this.presupuestoForm.get('concepto').value,
      base: this.presupuestoForm.get('base').value,
      tipo: this.presupuestoForm.get('tipo').value,
      iva: this.presupuestoForm.get('iva').value,
      total: this.presupuestoForm.get('total').value
    };
  }
```

No me esta persistiendo en mi tabla. Alguna ayuda.

Comment: y donde te conectas a postgress??

Comment: Esta forma la vi en un manual,debería ser mediante la variable `presURL = 'localhost/presupuesto.json'` con la direccion de mi base de datos lo que aun no entiendo es porque con .json

Comment: y ya hiciste el recurso que responde a `localhost/presupuesto.json`???

Comment: No, no lo he hecho. Existe otra forma de conectarme a la base de datos que no sea mediante un **.json**??

Comment: Lo que pusiste no es un forma de conexión. Necesitas buscar mas en internet antes de preguntar. https://expressjs.com/es/guide/database-integration.html

Comment: desde angular no es posible acceder a una base de datos directamente, tendrias que crear un pequeño backend en mongo, spring, php o django

Answer (score 1):

Para poder persistir los datos en tu Base de Datos debes tener a algún sistema de back-end que se comunique con tu front-end. O sea, **debes tener un API que para ciertas URLs te emita un resultado**.

En este caso que lo que quieres es insertar datos lo debes hacer a través del método POST (existen otros como GET, DELETE, PUT, etc).

Si estás empezando con Angular y te hace falta un API te aconsejo que intentes montarla con Node, específicamente Express, ya que es javascript y es bien sencillo, luego busca un ORM que se encargue de comunicarse con tu Base de Datos.

Comment: Lo respondo por aqui porque no tengo los puntos necesarios para adicionarte un comentario. Saludos

Comment: Si, ya me di cuenta, ya casi estoy cerca, me disculpo con todos.

Comment: @LeandroManuelHernandezMira no me referia a persistir sino a obtener los datos de una tabla de una base de datos **postgreSQL** en mi componente.

Comment: @AS13L tu pregunta dice "persistir", pero en caso de que quieras obtener los datos sería de la misma forma lo que con el verbo HTTP GET. Lo que si debes montarte un API que te sirva los datos.